# How to autofill fields in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i hope you can help me with this, i've been trying to make a form that autofills a field using the concatenation of two fields on the same form, but with no success, this is my model and my form

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name_doctor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_doctor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_doctor = models.EmailField()
    p_doctor = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    id_doctor = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name_doctor, self.last_doctor)
```

And my form:

```
class ADoctor(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('name_doctor', 'last_doctor', 'email_doctor', 'p_doctor', 'id_doctor')
        labels = {
            'name_doctor': ('Name'),
            'last_doctor': ('Last name'),
            'email_doctor': ('Email'),
            'p_doctor': ('Phone'),
            'id_doctor': ('ID'),
        }
```

How can i override the save so that when i send the form the field id_doctor fills with the concatenation of name_doctor + last_doctor ?

Comment: Since this needs to happen on the client side, do this with JavaScript.  Otherwise, if there is no need for the user to edit that field, create the ID field back in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: don't bother.

Whenever you can generate some item of data based on the content of one or more fields on the table, you do not need to create another field for it. And your `name_doctor` + `last_doctor` is a classic example of this.

Your model already has a name_doctor field as well as a last_doctor field, it's a trivial matter to display them by combining them together. There is no need to save it to the database and you shouldn't.

Edit: You can produce any custom combination of fields by just adding a method to the model example:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):


     def concat_fields(self):
          return self.name_doctor + self.last_doctor

     def quasi_unique_id(self):
          return self.name_doctor[0:2] + self.last_doctor[0:2] + id_order(some_other_model)
```

Comment: i'm doing this because after i achieve this i want to generate a custom tag based on the first two letters of the name and the two letters of the last name plus a number.

Comment: Still my answer is valid. You can do that with the name_doctor and last_doctor fields

Comment: But i still need to store it on a field of the model to be able to use that info on a different model and view to add extra information.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: i want to generate a custom order id on another form and model with a custom format but using a unique identifier not only a pk, something like this: name_doctor(first two letters)  +  last_doctor(first two letters) + "-" + id_order(from other model), for example, jane doe = ja+do+"-"+"1" = jado-1.

Comment: There is a way to make that (name_doctor + last_doctor) in my form view before run the form save and instead of override the save method? I'm still pretty new on this

Comment: There is no assurance that the scheme in your 'unique order id' will produce a unique one. I suspect that it will not be.

Answer (score -1):

***SOLVED***, i just added this before my post.save on my form def on my views.py

```
post.id_doctor = form['name_doctor'].value() + form['last_doctor'].value()
                post.save()
```

Comment: If you want to combine some fields you already have in the database, please implement them as methods on your model, ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Also, it's better to implement 'business rules' like this on your model instead of in the view. Otherwise, if you'd later add a different view where you can create 'doctors' you'll have to duplicate the code.